# ASP.NET button click event

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am new to asp.net, and I was asked to build a restful API with the platform, I managed and got to build the API perfectly and it is working 100%, I now have to build a front-end for the API. it is just to manage email layout. the API is used to capture details, post into DB, and send emails. That portion is working.

My problem comes here, with the front-end, the whole MVC structure I cant seem to understand.

My goal: to have c# code executed when a button is clicked.

The first page I want to build is a login page. I already wrote all the c# models to create the user and save into db. I just want to figure out HOW to run my c# functions when a button is clicked.

It does not help to use asp:button because I cant generate click event for there is no c# code behind pages... the views I am using are MCV 5 view page (razor)

my HTML markup:

```
<div class="lg-conatiner">

        <h1>Create an account</h1>

        <div class="loginBox registerBox">

            <div class="loginItem">


                <input placeholder="company name" />

            </div>

            <div class="loginItem">


                <input placeholder="username" />

            </div>

            <div class="loginItem">

                <input placeholder="password" type="password" />

            </div>

            <div class="loginItem">

                <input placeholder="confirm password" type="password" />

            </div>

            <div class="loginItem loginItem3">

               <button onclick="" type="button">Register</button>


                


                <a href="">@Html.ActionLink("Back to Login", "Login", "Account")</a>

            </div>
           
        </div>


    </div>
```

the c# function I want to run when the button is clicked:

```
public void registerUser(User newUser)
        {
            dataAccess da = new dataAccess();

           if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newUser.username) || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newUser.password) || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newUser.companyname))
            {
                try
                {

                    //all good, register user
                    da.insertUser(newUser);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
        }
```

the data access class just contains a function that runs my SQL stored procedure to insert a user.

Comment: MVC doesn't try to be a desktop development experience like webforms. You should [run through a tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) to get a feel for how it works.

Comment: For example, thinking of it as "running C# code when a button is clicked" is the wrong approach. Instead, a button click can cause a form to submit, or an asynchronous HTTP call via AJAX/[HTTP Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). Then on the server side, you define a controller action method that takes in the details from that HTTP request, processes it, and returns some sort of response.

Comment: By the way, never do `throw ex;` where `ex` is a caught exception. You lose your stack trace when you do that, which makes debugging difficult. Instead, just use `throw;`. Or better yet, in this case your try/catch block serves absolutely no purpose, and can be removed completely.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the thorough reply, im and intern dev, still learning  a lot :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways through which you can send your data to your `Controller` method on the server. I will show you how a very basic way on you can achieve your registration functionality using a strongly typed `Model` that will hold your registration details and then send it to the server for processing:

Create a `Model` under your Model directory called Register:

```
public class Register
{
    [Required]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Then initialize this `Model` when you are rendering your initial view. Under your Controllers folder, create a new controller called `Register` and inside that define a method called `Index`. This method is responsible for setting up your Index view with the model bind to the fields:

```
using project.Models;

public class RegisterController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Register register = new Register();
        return View(register);
    }
}
```

Now this controller method is responsible for routing the action to the Index view with the Register model. You can use `HtmlHelpers` to bind the value of the input to the model value like this. You should wrap your elements in a `form` that you will post to your `Controller`:

`Index.cshtml`:

```
@using project.Models
@model Register

<div class="lg-conatiner">
    <h1>Create an account</h1>
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, null, new { @class = "text-danger", style = "font-size:20px"})
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Register", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form", role = "form", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div class="loginBox registerBox">
            <div class="loginItem">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CompanyName , new { @id = "companynameID", @class = "form-control", @required = "required", @placeholder = "Enter Company Name", @autocomplete = "off" })           
            </div>
            <div class="loginItem">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName , new { @id = "usernameID", @class = "form-control", @required = "required", @placeholder = "username", @autocomplete = "off" })               
                <input placeholder="username" />
            </div>
            <div class="loginItem">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Password, new { @id = "passwordID", @class = "form-control", @required = "required", @placeholder = "Enter Password", @autocomplete = "off", @type = "password" })      
                <input placeholder="password" type="password" />
            </div>
            <div class="loginItem">
                <input placeholder="confirm password" type="password" id="confirmpasswordID"/>
            </div>      
            <div class="loginItem loginItem3">
               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Register</button>
            </div>      
        </div>
    }
    <br>
    <a href="">@Html.ActionLink("Back to Login", "Login", "Account")</a>    
</div>
```

The above View uses `Bootstrap` elements to display the form. We also use the `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` which you can read more on [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-attacks)

Now once your view is setup, you can `Post` your data to the `Controller` like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Register(Register register)
{
    dataAccess da = new dataAccess();
    try
    {
        var result= da.insertUser(register);
        if(!da)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Could not register");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Successfully registered");                
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Exception in registering user");
        //Log the exception
    }           
    return View("Index", register);
}
```

There are other ways also in which you can send your form data to your `Controller` methods like using `AJAX` or `JQuery` to validate your elements first and then send them to `Controller`. The above implementation is a basic outline of how you can post your data through a `Model`.

Comment: Hi Rahul, First off, thank you so much for your detailed answer.. it really helped me understand MVC much better, I have found my solution thanks to your post!